# Can I use Webrat for ASP.NET applications?

Tags: asp.net, webrat, web-testing

Does Webrat require that the web application be written in Ruby/Rails?

I'd like to try it for writing tests against an ASP.NET web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use webrat for any application, not just Rails. What you do is to use Cucumber + Webrat + Mechanize adapter. This combination makes ordinary HTTP requests against your web application.

In fact, for the moment, i'm working on a simple smoketest that tests a website portal and can verify that everything is up and running in different environments. (localhost, test env, staging, production).

Have a look in Cucumbers' source. There is an example in the folder:
[cucumber/examples/webrat/](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/tree/master/examples/webrat)

What you do is to tell Webrat to use the Mechanize adapter. Now you have a headless browser that can access any application regardless of the framework it uses.

Note that if you need full javascript support, you probably want something else (Watir,Firewatir, Selenium, etc).

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping that was the case.  I'm trying to learn Ruby anyway so this is a great excuse to hone those skills.  I hope to prove this soon and call this the answer!

Comment: Good to hear. I just did the same thing last week, and found the example in the folder cucumber/examples/webrat folder. It's pretty straight forward, and easy as the example already has running code :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to jump to rails :P I stumbled upon this post because I was thinking that would be very handy.

Have a look at [Cuke4Nuke](http://github.com/richardlawrence/Cuke4Nuke)

Also checkout the authors blog, there is a nice [screencast](http://www.richardlawrence.info/2009/12/03/screencast-testing-web-applications-in-net-with-cuke4nuke-and-watin/) but it uses WatiN

There is also some discussion here about eventually being able to build the equivalent of webrat for mvc

https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/16211-cucumber/tickets/428-wire-protocol

Comment: Thanks Jake.  I've looked at Cuke4Nuke.  All of my Ruby buddies use Cucumber and WebRat.  I was thinking if WebRat just uses HTTP that it could work for any web site.

Comment: Hey I just saw this as well which I think would help you test asp.net web apps http://blog.codeville.net/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/